# How to cache wp_query with pagination using transients?

Tags: wp-query, pagination, transient, cache

I have seen examples where there is a fix number of posts to be queried; however, I cant find an example when using pagination.

I am trying to figure out how to use transients to cache a WP_Query with paging.

So far, I am showing 12 posts per page. When I load the next set of posts, the posts are the same first 12 posts. It is not getting the following posts.

Comment: Post your code please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a unique transient key for each page of posts otherwise each page will output same posts.

Here is a example. Focus on `get_transient` & `set_transient` functions.

```
<?php

  $my_posts_query = get_transient( 'my_unique_transient_key_' . get_query_var( 'paged' ) );

  if( false === $my_posts_query ) {

    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => '12', 'paged' => $paged );
    $my_posts_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    set_transient( 'my_unique_transient_key_' . get_query_var( 'paged' ), $my_posts_query, 300 );
  }

  if ( $my_posts_query->have_posts() ) :

    while ( $my_posts_query->have_posts() ) :

      $my_posts_query->the_post();

      // Your loop

    endwhile;

    // This is responsible for 1, 2, 3 pagination links. You can easily change this to previous and nexys links.
    if ( $my_posts_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) :
      $big = 999999999;
      echo '<div class="pagination">';
      echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $my_posts_query->max_num_pages
      ) );
      echo '</div>';
    endif;

  endif;

  wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Comment: Thats awesome, i will test it when I get home. Thanks.

Comment: Did it work? The code I posted. Let me know.

Comment: Hey Robert, I havent tested it yet but it looks like it works. I up voted it for now. Once I test it, I'll checked it as solved.

Comment: Finally I got to test it. It's perfect!

Comment: I found one issue. Transients for each page get different expiration times; thus, when one expires and the other hasnt, repeated posts appear. Could you please tell me a way to fix this? Thank you.